# Jquery highlight and show more/less function are not working together

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem where when I try to search for a word to give me the highlight effect while I have pressed the show more button it will close the show more and only show the text before you have pressed the button.

How do I make it so that it stays open while i'm searching for a word.

My html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bootstrap/test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <input class="text_search" id=x placeholder="text">
    <div id=text_x>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p class="content">
            Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
            </p>
            <p class="more-cont" style="display:none;">
            Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loa
            <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender 
            borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to 
            </p>
            <a class="Show_more_less">Show more</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p class="content">
            Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
            </p>
            <p class="more-cont" style="display:none;">
            Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loa
            <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender 
            borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to 
            </p>
            <a class="Show_more_less">Show more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p class="content">
            Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
            </p>
            <p class="more-cont" style="display:none;">
            Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loa
            <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender 
            borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to 
            </p>
            <a class="Show_more_less">Show more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Show_more_less').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).text(function(i, t) {
          return t == 'Show less' ? 'Show more' : 'Show less';
        }).prev('.more-cont').slideToggle()
    });
});

$(function() {

    $(".text_search").each(function() {

        var textModal = $('#text_' + this.id),html = textModal.html();

        $(this).on("keyup", function() {

            var reg = new RegExp($(this).val() || "&fakeEntity;", 'gi');

            textModal.html(html.replace(reg, function(str, index) {

                var t = html.slice(0, index+1),
                    lastLt = t.lastIndexOf("<"),
                    lastGt = t.lastIndexOf(">"),
                    lastAmp = t.lastIndexOf("&"),
                    lastSemi = t.lastIndexOf(";");

                if(lastLt > lastGt) return str;
                if(lastAmp > lastSemi) return str;
                return "<span class='highlight'>" + str + "</span>";
            }));
        });
    }); 
});
```

my css code

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background-color: rgb(241, 238, 238);
}
.Show_more_less{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.text_search{
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can save the state of elements and its ID on key-up function like this:

```
    var more = "";

    $(this).on("keyup", function() {

var state = document.getElementsByClassName("more-cont");
$( state ).each(function( index ) {
if(this.style.display === ""){
    more = more.concat(this.id+",");
  }
});
```

And revert it back like this:

```
var res = more.split(",");
      for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
        [].forEach.call(res, function(el) {
        if (el !==""){
          document.getElementById(el).style.display = "";
          }
        });
```

**Working solution:**

```js
function bindShowMoreLess(){
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Show_more_less').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(function(i, t) {
      return t == 'Show less' ? 'Show more' : 'Show less';
    }).prev('.more-cont').slideToggle()
  });
});
}

$(document).ready(bindShowMoreLess);


$(function() {

  $(".text_search").each(function() {

    var textModal = $('#text_' + this.id),
      html = textModal.html();

    var more = [];

    $(this).on("keyup", function() {

var state = document.getElementsByClassName("more-cont");
$( state ).each(function( index ) {
if(this.style.display === ""){
    more.push(this.id); 
    return more;
  }
});



      var reg = new RegExp($(this).val() || "&fakeEntity;", 'gi');

      textModal.html(html.replace(reg, function(str, index) {

        var t = html.slice(0, index + 1),
          lastLt = t.lastIndexOf("<"),
          lastGt = t.lastIndexOf(">"),
          lastAmp = t.lastIndexOf("&"),
          lastSemi = t.lastIndexOf(";");

        if (lastLt > lastGt) return str;
        if (lastAmp > lastSemi) return str;
        return "<span class='highlight'>" + str + "</span>";

      }));
      
bindShowMoreLess();

      for (var i = 0, len = more.length; i < len; i++) {
        [].forEach.call(more, function(el) {
        if (el !==""){
          document.getElementById(el).style.display = "";                
          $("#"+el).next("a").text("Show less");
          }
        });
      };
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: rgb(241, 238, 238);
}

.Show_more_less {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text_search {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bootstrap/test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <input class="text_search" id="x" placeholder="text">
    <div id=text_x>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="content">
          Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
        </p>
        <p class="more-cont" id="more-cont1" style="display:none;">
          Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loa
          <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to
        </p>
        <a class="Show_more_less">Show more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="content">
          Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
        </p>
        <p class="more-cont" id="more-cont2" style="display:none;">
          Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loa
          <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to
        </p>
        <a class="Show_more_less">Show more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="content">
          Several Australian home owners have been utilizing the services of mortgage brokers to fulfill their dreams of owning a house at an affordable rate.
        </p>
        <p class="more-cont" id="more-cont3" style="display:none;">
          Whether you are aspiring to buy a new house or considering upgrading your existing home loa
          <br>Mortgage broking involves the act of intermediating between the borrower and the lender borrower’s behalf. The role of mortgage broker starts right from the time when you plan to
        </p>
        <a class="Show_more_less">Show more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried the code??? It is not working sir. Try search and then try to click show more link. It doesnt work even in your posted answer.

Comment: @maverickosama92 It works for me. What are you talking about? It stays open and highlight the phrase... Your solution does not stays open, and OP mentioned he wants that.

Comment: @maverickosama92 Your solution does not even answer the problem OP wants to solve:  "it will close the show more and only show the text before you have pressed the button." In my if you open something it stays open.

Comment: @ikiK he is right when you try to close it after you have search for some thing it's not close again. when you search from the start without clicking the button it will not open

Comment: @nicolaj1449 Ill try to fix that too, but still, you asked for a shown item to stay open, hes solution is not complete ether.

Comment: @nicolaj1449 Actually if you'd just combine this two you will get all you need...

Comment: @ikiK i can see that it works just fine now but for some reason it's still not working in my  html code like it does in the snippet. And i tried as you said to combine them but it's still the same result i get

Comment: @nicolaj1449 I fixed it all now, see snippet code. Had also problem when hidden stayed open button switched  to show more after serach, now its back to show less.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're replacing html when searching in you would need to rebind after searching and replacing or highlighting.

try this:

```
function bindShowMoreLess(){
    $('.Show_more_less').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).text(function(i, t) {
          return t == 'Show less' ? 'Show more' : 'Show less';
        }).prev('.more-cont').slideToggle()
    });

}

$(document).ready(bindShowMoreLess);

$(function() {

    $(".text_search").each(function() {

        var textModal = $('#text_' + this.id),html = textModal.html();

        $(this).on("keyup", function() {

            var reg = new RegExp($(this).val() || "&fakeEntity;", 'gi');

            textModal.html(html.replace(reg, function(str, index) {

                var t = html.slice(0, index+1),
                    lastLt = t.lastIndexOf("<"),
                    lastGt = t.lastIndexOf(">"),
                    lastAmp = t.lastIndexOf("&"),
                    lastSemi = t.lastIndexOf(";");

                if(lastLt > lastGt) return str;
                if(lastAmp > lastSemi) return str;
                return "<span class='highlight'>" + str + "</span>";
            }));
            
            bindShowMoreLess();
        });
    }); 
});
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wvbcxj50/